# Google Map Store Locator Functionality using Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps, google-docs

I'm in the process of building a store locator functionality for a site.  I've come across the docs for the Google Store Locator:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Overall looks straight forward, but the only foreseeable problem is populating the DB to grab the locations as outlined in their docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#populatetable

This is doable by someone comfortable with PHP MyAdmin, but ideally I'll like to grab the info from something like Google Docs Spreadsheet.  I can forsee the client getting into the DB and goofing things up but if something like Google Docs was updated by them, it'd be a lot safer.  Curious if anyone has done this before or found any good documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [google fusion tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/public/tour/index.html#)